# unpacking serial data "01 04 04 3f 9f 97 00 a9 8e"

Tags: python-3.x, sensors

I got lt-1400(water level transmitter), output(RS485), I send this(b'\x01\x04\x00\x02\x00\x02\xd0\x0b\x00\x00\x00') to USB to TTL max485 and I resiveing tis kind of data (b'\x01\x04\x04\x3f\x9f\xae\x80\xba\x7e').how can I translate it.
receiving and sending data I am using python script||||||||

```
`
import serial 
import time          # import the module
while True:
    ComPort = serial.Serial('COM11') # open COM3
    ComPort.baudrate = 9600 # set Baud rate to 9600
    ComPort.bytesize = 8    # Number of data bits = 8
    ComPort.parity   = 'N'  # No parity
    ComPort.stopbits = 1    # Number of Stop bits = 1
    data = bytearray(b'\x01\x04\x00\x02\x00\x02\xd0\x0b\x00\x00\x00')
    No = ComPort.write(data)
    print (ComPort.isOpen())
    #print(data)                      # print the data
    dataIn = ComPort.read(8)        # Wait and read data
    print(dataIn) 
    ComPort.close()                          # print the received data
    #time.sleep(2)
ComPort.close()         # Close the Com port `
```

||||||||||||||||||||||
translating data python script|||||||

```
`
import struct
data = bytearray(b'\x01\x04\x04\x3f\x9f\xae\x80\xba\x7e')
number = struct.unpack('hhl', data)
number=str(number)
print(number)
#print(num2)
`
```

however, I have everything still I don't get the necessary data please help me If you can I would be happy

Comment: There should be (somewhere) some technical documentation, which can explain the meaning of the returned info.

Comment: there's nothing. no any documentation about this sensor